# Magnto 2 : varnish cache issue?

Tags: magento2, varnish

The current website running on **Magento 2.2.4 CE** and we have enabled **varnish cache**.

**How do we know if varnish cache is working or not in Magento 2?**

Please advise?

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20747210/how-to-check-if-varnish-cache-is-working-correctly?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow Magento 2 devdocs as they told step to step setting and configuration of varnish cache.
If you have already installed varnish cache on your server then you need to configure Port in admin of Developer section then you will require to final verification that it's working or not as per below guideline of Devdoc Magento 2:

> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-final.html

Full configuration Guide:

> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish.html

**As per Magento Docs,you can also check that Varnish cache working or not as per below steps:**

**Make sure the /var/page_cache directory is empty:**

**Step1:** Log in to your Magento server, or switch to, the Magento file system owner.

**Step2:** Clear page_cache manually with below command

```
  rm -rf <your Magento install dir>/var/page_cache/*
```

**Step3:** Access one or more cacheable Magento pages by navigate some page randomly.

**Step4:** Check the var/page_cache/ directory.

If the directory is empty, congratulations! You successfully configured Varnish and Magento to work together!
If you cleared the var/page_cache/ directory, restart Varnish.

Comment: thanks @akgola let me check and get back

Comment: I have followed all the steps but i would like to know whether varnish cache working or not how to do?

Answer (score 0):

According to Magento, you can perform some final verifications to make sure **Varnish is working.**
 One of which is [Verifying HTTP response headers](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-final.html#config-varnish-final-verify-headers)

First, make sure you are using **Magento’s developer mode;** otherwise, you won’t see the headers.

For example,

```
curl -I -v --location-trusted 'http://192.0.2.55/magento2'
```

Important headers:

```
X-Magento-Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public, s-maxage=86400
Age: 0
X-Magento-Cache-Debug: MISS
```

> This value is also acceptable: **X-Magento-Cache-Debug: HIT**.
>
> If you get a **MISS** value in that header, **Varnish is (for some reason) unable or unwilling to cache your content.**

Comment: thanks for your valuable info. let me check and get back to u

Comment: Hi @Magefms i am getting X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront  is this an issue?

Comment: are you using aws?

Comment: yes, I think so @magefms

Comment: try this https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-latency-xcache/

Comment: Hi @magefms one small query, currently varnish cache enabled, but when we doing any changes at magento 2 admin end for example: product changes price,name etc (or) cms changes it is effecting immediately in the front end. Now my query is whether varnish cache working or not, how do we decide?

Comment: what do you mean by how we decide? wether to enable or disable varnish?

Comment: I think if you want to disable varnish you can just revert the settings of Magento to use the default Built-in cache. Then you can use regular flushing of cache afterward.

Comment: Thanks @magefms can we purge varnish cache from magento cache clean? do u have any idea please suggest?

Comment: Yes , please check this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/varnish/use-varnish-cache.html#use-varnish-magento-purge

Comment: How can I resolve when my header is not return X-Magento-Cache-Debug: HIT ?